# Whats the cleanest was to access the parent of nested routes "/projects/1" and "/projects/1/something"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, most stuff is nested in a project, so routes look like this:

```
/projects/1

/projects/1/status_form

/projects/1/message_board
```

When the URI is `/projects/1` then I can access the `current_project` with `Project.find(params[:id])`, when its `/projects/1/status_form` I use `Project.find(params[:project_id])`

Some routes do are not nested within a project, like:

```
/users/edit
```

I want to write a method that accesses the current project (if there is one, like the first two links), or returns nil if there isn't one (like last link). What is the cleanest way to do this?

The last part that makes it a bit more tricky. If a user has multiple projects (1, 2, and 3), and they go to `users/edit/` then back to home (which redirects to a project), it should remember the most recent project

Here is my current implementation, but it seems complicated. Is there a better way?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  ## This is used to remember most recent project
  before_filter :current_params_project


  def current_params_project
    session[:current_project_id] = params[:project_id] if params[:project_id]
  end

  def current_project

    ## this returns if @current_project is set in the projects#show
    return @current_project if @current_project

    if params[:project_id]
      project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
    elsif session[:current_project_id]
      project = Project.find_by_id(session[:current_project_id])
    elsif current_user and current_user.projects
      project = current_user.projects.first
    end
    project
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extract that logic into several methods. As a result the `current_project` method would be much simpler:

```
before_action :remember_most_recent_project

private

def remember_most_recent_project
  session[:recent_project_id] = current_project.id if current_project
end

def project
  @project ||= Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
end

def recent_project
  @recent_project ||= Project.find_by_id(session[:recent_project_id])
end

def user_project
  current_user && current_user.projects.first
end

def current_project
  @current_project ||= project || recent_project || user_project        
end
```